# Handle VideoView Fullscreen and Portrait with Rotation and Button

Tags: android, fullscreen, portrait, android-videoview

I have a tricky situation. I can put the VideoView in fullscreen Mode when the device is in Landscape and change to Portrait mode with the Android rotation. The problem is I want to put a Button option to this job also.

How can I force the device enter in landscape mode by code or there is another way to do this?

Thanks.

Regards,
Bernas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call this from your onClick listener in your activity to force landscape mode

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);`

Comment: I tried to use that option but after the rotation option stays disabled. How can I check if the user already rotated the device to turn on again the sensor:         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR); ?

Comment: Yes that will work or you can use SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED to go back to the system default (including whatever the user set)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. So you are saying to set SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED on OnCreate method will reset the configuration? Or there is a better place to set this?

Comment: I set the SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED  in onCreate method but the app does not give time for the user to rotate the phone. It turns to Portrait right away. To avoid this problem I set a timer to 5 sec to set the SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED. There is other way to do this?